# Missing return statement java compilation error vs. inner method exception

Tags: java, exception

Can somebody explain to me why the following code is OK for java compiler:

```
private InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resourceName) {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
}

private byte[] readResourceToByteArray(String resourceName) {
    try (InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionFailedError();
    }
}
```

But in the following one:

```
private InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resourceName) {
    return getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
}

private byte[] readResourceToByteArray(String resourceName) {
    try (InputStream in = getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throwException();
    }
}

private void throwException() {
    throw new AssertionFailedError();
}
```

I'm getting missing return statement java compilation error in method readResourceToByteArray() if it is clear that in catch block I'm throwing exception so no return should be needed ?

Comment: Because the second snippet has a method call instead of directly throwing an exception. The compiler is able to understand that `throw new AssertionFailedError();` will result in an exception (hence the first snippet compiles fine), but it's not smart enough to know that `throwException()` will internally behave the same (so the second snippet won't compile).

Comment: What would happen if `throwException()` did not throw an exception?

Comment: The compiler doesn't inspect the contents of `throwException` when it parses the call, so it doesn't know that it throws an exception.

Comment: throwException() ..if you add a throws clause to this method, it will compile, else compiler has no way of knowing that an exception is being thrown by it

Comment: @akshayapandey "if you add a throws clause to this method, it will compile" ... no it won't. (at least not in Java 8, but I doubt that has been changed in later versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you are actually throwing an `Exception` which is known to the compiler at compile time, therefore no additional return statement is required.

In your second example, you are calling a method which may or may not throw an exception, compiler is not sure about this, therefore it is asking you for a return statement.